# Accessing to models methods "def()" from a query Django

Tags: python, django

im fighting with something here i'm using django and may you can help me.

I got a Account model with a date_of_birth field, and i have a method for find out the age.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     date_of_birth   = models.DateField()
     def age(self):
        """
        Returns the age from the date of birth
        """
        today = datetime.date.today()
        try: 
            birthday = self.date_of_birth.replace(year=today.year)
        except ValueError: # raised when birth date is February 29 and the current year is not a leap year
            birthday = self.date_of_birth.replace(year=today.year, day=self.date_of_birth.day-1)
        if birthday > today:
            return today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - 1
        else:
            return today.year - self.date_of_birth.year
```

i was wondering if is possible to obtain the age from a query like this:

```
list = Account.objects.filter('account__age__gte', today)
```

i tried already but i got this error:

> cannot resolve keyword 'age' into field. Choices are:......

and only shows me the fields. not the methods.\

i appreciate your help.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly query against model method, since custom methods cannot evaluate to their corresponding SQL queries.

You have a couple of options instead:

In the view, compute the earliest date of birth given the age. Example 24 years:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(years=24)
datetime.date(1989, 11, 15)
```

and now, the query would be on the `date_of_birth` field.

Note that `dateutil` is a 3rd party library and may not be available with your python by default.  (If you want to use timedelta, you could do that too, since `datetime.timedelta` is python builtin)

Another option (a little less efficient) is to fetch the object queryset, and use a list comprehension to filter out the unwanted records.

```
qs = Account.objects.all()

qs = [account for account in qs if account.age() > 24]
```

24, obviously was just an example. replace that with some "sane" value.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have an answer for this already and that answer is accurate, but I think you might benefit from making your age method into a property (actually, I thought this is what is what model properties were for, but I would be happy to be corrected on this point if I am wrong).

Thus, you could do something like this:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    date_of_birth   = models.DateField()
    def _age(self):
       """
       Returns the age from the date of birth
       """
       today = datetime.date.today()
       ... {value is computed and returned} ...
    age = property(_age)
```

This, of course, doesn't solve your filtering problem; it just makes it easier to treat the method as if it's an instance attribute and your SQL query will still need to grab everything, or filter by `date_of_birth` (which if you're going to do a lot, may be nice to include as a custom manager).